# How to support dynamic plugins when statically linking in standard libraries?

Tags: c++, gcc, ld, libstdc++

Suppose an application `myapp.exe` is built using `g++` and it uses the flag `-static-libstdc++` so that it can be installed in enviroments without `libstdc++.so`. `myapp.exe` also adds plugin support for some function `plugf` that can be dynamically loading via `dlopen` from a shard library.

If `libplug.so` is such a plugin library that also links to `libstdc++`, how can it do so in a way to be able to work with `myapp.exe`?

This is straightforward if `libstdc++` is linked in dynamically since both `myapp.exe` and `libplug.so` can use the same dynamically loaded standard library, but it's not clear to me how best to do this with statically linked standard libraries.

An approach I'm considering is to have `libplug.so` also use the flag `-static-libstdc++` and then use the [version script](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_25.html)

```
{
  global: plugf;
  local: *;
};
```

to ensure that its version of the standard library is used, but that would mean there would be two copies of `libstdc++` loaded into memory. I know this approach wouldn't be blessed by the C++ standard since it would have ORD violations, but is it something that `libstdc++` supports in any way? The `Multiple ABI testing` section of its [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html) section does reference a scenario that sounds similar.

Comment: Sadly, you're going to need to distribute a dynamic/static linked libstdc++ to match `libplug.so` - and yes, two copies would be loaded at runtime. And yes, you might get in trouble if your plugin returns a pointer with one version of libstdc++ and you free it with another version.

Comment: I don't think that's true. Allocation is handled by the standard c library and `-static-libstdc++` doesn't cause `libc` to be linked in statically so they are both using the same `libc.so`.

Comment: I think objects are allocated with `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator` in libstdc++, perhaps as you point out they both go to the same `libc.so`. From personal experience I've had the aforementioned problem using MSVC's RT.

Comment: A standard allocation such as `new int{123}` calls `operator new` which in libstdc++ is just a wrapper for malloc. (See [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/ba9cddfdab8b539b788cd6fe0171351ae43c32da/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/new_op.cc#L50)).

Comment: Yeah, depends on how you build it, for example you might be mixing different version of libc. This is why libraries like those from HDL don't expose memory allocation. Anyways, systems that support dynamic plugins rely on dynamic libraries do avoid duplication. That is why dlls were invented. One way to mitigate the impact of your deployment strategy is to rely heavily on LTO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this solution would work but

- it introduces certain overhead due to code duplication
- it may break if you try to pass STL objects between plugin/app due to [ABI changes in recent libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Cxx11AbiCompatibility)

Deleting objects allocated by `std::allocator` in different C++ runtime should work on Linux although I could not find explicit statement about this in libstdc++ docs. It does fail on Windows as Mikhail pointed out in comments.

Comment: The ABI changes are only between the C++98 and C++11 versions of libstdc++, though, right?

Comment: @rnickb No, you'll get new ABI in all post-GCC5 libstdc++ regardless of `-std` flag (see [this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html) for more details). It kind of makes sense because `std::string` in code compiled with `-std=c++98` and `-std=c++11` should better be binary compatible.